# Selecting values from table of type

Tags: collections, plsql

I created a definitions table,T_DEFINITION
This table has 2 columns: category_id and included_service_list.
/*There are many columns which are working like INCLUDED_SERVICE_LIST logic, so I wrote one of them to make the question simple*/
Sample of table is:

```
CATEGORY_ID    INCLUDED_SERVICE_LIST
18             24,37,86,102,125,144,226,285
24             12,25,33,49,52,55,58,63,69,70,80,90,107
```

and values go on like this.

In my select statement; I want to query INCLUDED_SERVICE_LIST column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_TRANSACTION A,T_DEFINITION B
WHERE A.SERVICE_ID IN (string.split(B.INCLUDED_SERVICE_LIST))
```

I need to split the string in the INCLUDED_SERVICE_LIST column and use it in select statement.
`string.split` is my custom split function, which returns a table of varchar2.

But I do not know how to select values from the output table of varchar2.
Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any other join between T_TRANSACTION and T_DEFINITION?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T_TRANSACTION A,T_DEFINITION B
 WHERE A.SERVICE_ID IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                          FROM TABLE(string.split(B.INCLUDED_SERVICE_LIST)))
```

This should work if your `string.split` is defined to return a *nested table* - something like this

```
/* Type definition */
TYPE T_VARCHARS IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);

/* Function definition */
FUNCTION split(v VARCHAR2) RETURNING T_VARCHARS;
```

Actually, if you are using oracle 11g, you can create columns that hold nested tables, instead of long varchars of comma-joined numbers - below is an example of such design.

```
/* Create user type */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_NUMBERS AS TABLE OF NUMBER(30);

/* Create table with column holding a nested table */
CREATE TABLE T_DEFINITION (
    CATEGORY_ID NUMBER,
    INCLUDED_SERVICE_LIST T_NUMBERS
) NESTED TABLE INCLUDED_SERVICE_LIST STORED AS T_DEF_SERVICE_LIST;
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from table(string.split(param_value));

Comment: You should use the names as its in the question to help others to understand your answer. Thank you.